# Add border to table in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to use gtk table in one of my projects(GUI based) to show a pair of columns and its values. Since gtk table doesn't have borders by default, my GUI is not coming up well.

So,
Is there anyway I can add borders to gtk table and its cells?

If no can I create a customized widget with borders by extending gtk Table?

How can I create a customized widget in pygtk?

P.S: I have tried gtk Treeview and gtk Frames and thats not what I want. Also I have created a gtk treeview for each pair of columns and its values but the GUI works very very slow.

Comment: You can use `Table.set_row_spacings()` & `Table.set_col_spacings()` to control the spacing between elements in the Table. Have you used  `.set_border_width()` on your GUI's main window? Maybe you should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can see what your GUI looks like; that will also make it a _lot_ easier for us to offer suggestions on how to improve its appearance.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm guessing from his use of GtkFrame that he wants a border around the entire table.

Comment: @user2109788 Is the Python equivalent of `gtk_scrolled_window_set_shadow_type(GTK_SHADOW_IN)` what you're looking for? You call it on the scrolled window you put your table in. This is the way glade puts a border around GtkTreeViews.

Comment: @andlabs: Sure, they want a border around the whole table, but if the table's the only thing in the window, then increasing the border width (and possibly the window size) could do the trick. And from the info in the 2nd paragraph it sounds like they also want to increase the spacing between the table cells.

Comment: @PM2Ring In that case we have a composite answer; let's find out...

Comment: @PM2Ring set_row_spacings and set_col_spanings will only crete spaces. But I want to add a solid border around all the cells of a  table.

Comment: @user2109788: Sure, but you _did_ say that you want to "add borders to gtk table _and_ its cells" so I figured you wanted some extra space _inside_ the Table, as well as around it. Have you added the Table directly to the Window? If so, please try `.set_border_width()` on your window, eg `win.set_border_width(20)`. If that's not good enough, you will need to place your Table inside another Widget, eg another Table, and call `.set_border_width()` on the outer Table. As I said above, all this would be easier to explain if you show us some of your code.

Comment: For the solid border, is your table in a scrolled window? As for your cells, do you mean that you want your table to have *grid lines* instead?

Comment: @andlabs My table is inside a gtk frame. So I can get the border for the table. And, yes I am looking for grid lines for table cells. Any suggestions?

Comment: The table being inside a GtkFrame is irrelevant here; you want the tale inside a GtkScrolledWindow first because that's what provides the scrollbars! When you create a GtkScrolledWindow in Glade and then drop a GtkTreeView in that, Glade will give the GtkScrolledWindow a shadow type of `GTK_SHADOW_IN`. That's what provides the border around the table in every other GTK+ application, not the GtkFrame. You can still have the GtkFrame if you want, but keep in mind that's more for grouping related controls together.

Comment: In code, you would use `scrolledWindow.set_shadow_type()`; I'm not sure what the Python equivalent of `GTK_SHADOW_IN` is. As for grid lines, you want the `set_grid_lines()` method of GtkTreeView. It takes a single parameter, which is a `GTK_TREE_VIEW_GRID_LINES_xxxx` constant where `xxxx` can be `NONE`, `HORIZONTAL`, `VERTICAL`, or `BOTH`. Again, I don't know what the Python equivalent constants are; a quick documentation search should reveal what they are. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want five pixels of spacing, if you would like to have space between the different cells of your table, you can try `table.set_row_spacings(5); table.set_col_spacings(5)`;  If you would like to have space around the entire table, you can do `table.set_padding(5)`.